# Altered AutoIncrement Id not being used in MySql + Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, insert, auto-increment

I use Hibernate and mySql.

I have defined the db script as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `Foo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `data` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
ALTER TABLE Foo AUTO_INCREMENT = 34324;
```

and this is my hibernate mapping:

```
<class name="org.xyz.Foo" table="Foo">
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="id" column="id">
         <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <version name="version" column="version"/>
    <property name="data" column="data"/>
</class>
```

Problem : The inserts are not respecting the AutoIncrement Id which is set as `34324`. The inserted Ids start from 1 instead of 34324 as I expected.
I am not setting Ids myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your hibernate mapping preferred generation strategy is `increment`. This means that Hibernate generates value. But according DDL column should be AUTO_INCREMENT, which means value is assigned by MySQL.

If AUTO_INCREMENT is what you want, solution is to use following Hibernate mapping:

```
<generator class="identity"/>
```